# How to access the object using the collection of laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have module where I need to insert all the each array object value in the database but today I got problem getting the object inside of the array when I try to dump the object it says that attempt to read property "customer" on array. Currently I used laravel my backend

Error:

> message: "Attempt to read property "customer" on array", exception: "ErrorException

Goal: Get each objects.

dump request all:

```
    array:1 [
  "value" => array:5 [
    0 => array:8 [
      "key" => "0"
      "customer" => "1"
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    1 => array:8 [
      "key" => "1"
      "customer" => "2"
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    2 => array:8 [
      "key" => "2"
      "customer" => null
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    3 => array:8 [
      "key" => "3"
      "customer" => null
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    4 => array:8 [
      "key" => "4"
      "customer" => null
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
  ]
]
```

Collection Items - dd($item):

```
 array:5 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "key" => "0"
    "customer" => "1"
    "bank" => null
    "branch" => null
    "checkNo" => null
    "amount" => null
    "remarks" => null
    "checkDate" => null
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "key" => "1"
    "customer" => "2"
    "bank" => null
    "branch" => null
    "checkNo" => null
    "amount" => null
    "remarks" => null
    "checkDate" => null
  ]
  2 => array:8 [
    "key" => "2"
    "customer" => null
    "bank" => null
    "branch" => null
    "checkNo" => null
    "amount" => null
    "remarks" => null
    "checkDate" => null
  ]
  3 => array:8 [
    "key" => "3"
    "customer" => null
    "bank" => null
    "branch" => null
    "checkNo" => null
    "amount" => null
    "remarks" => null
    "checkDate" => null
  ]
  4 => array:8 [
    "key" => "4"
    "customer" => null
    "bank" => null
    "branch" => null
    "checkNo" => null
    "amount" => null
    "remarks" => null
    "checkDate" => null
  ]
]
```

Result of dumping of rows:

```
    Illuminate\Support\Collection {#203
  #items: array:5 [
    0 => array:8 [
      "key" => "0"
      "customer" => "1"
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    1 => array:8 [
      "key" => "1"
      "customer" => "2"
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    2 => array:8 [
      "key" => "2"
      "customer" => null
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    3 => array:8 [
      "key" => "3"
      "customer" => null
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
    4 => array:8 [
      "key" => "4"
      "customer" => null
      "bank" => null
      "branch" => null
      "checkNo" => null
      "amount" => null
      "remarks" => null
      "checkDate" => null
    ]
  ]
}
```

Dump:

```
$rows = collect($request->value);

    $collection = $rows->map(function ($item) {


        dd($item['customer']);
       
    });
```

My Request Payload:

[image: Request Payload]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actual needed data was in `$request->value`. As error says, its array not collection of object. So i think should be

```
$rows = collect($request->value);

    $collection = $rows->map(function ($item) {

        
        dd($item['customer']);
       
});
```

or you can try

```
  $collection = $rows->map(function ((object)$item) {
    
            
            dd($item->customer);
           
    });
```

Comment: I already did that but the error says Undefined array key "customer"

Comment: can you give actual array.so i can test it to ensure

Comment: try dd($item) what you get

Comment: if I try that dd($item) the one I posted the collection Item. please see the new updated content I insert the screenshot of my payload

Comment: is that screenshot of dd($request->all()) or  dd($item)

Comment: then chaange $rows = collect($request->value);

Comment: hi i add new content details

Comment: What's happening now when I try to dd($item['customer']); it shows 1 string but when i var_dump it shows 2 string

Comment: just dd($item) and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234040/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-devge).